# dygraphs clickCallback from mobile device

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I'm using iPad with Chrome browser.  The graph appears properly but the clickCallback is not firing when I touch the screen on a graph.  I've a custom chart labels that I need to update when user clicks on any point in graph.  Is there any way to handle the touch of iPad and translate into clickCallback?

Thanks in advance